# How to validate POST request body required params in Pre-request script?

Tags: javascript, postman, postman-pre-request-script

I have few need-to-have params in JSON raw data in my request body and I want to validate in the pre-request script in Postman if those params are present in the body or not.

```
{
  "stores": [
    {
      "city": "Tokyo",
      "name": "Church Street"
      ....
      ....
    }
  ]
}
```

How to check if `city` and `name` is passed or not in the request body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `pm.test` function with the `pm.expect` assertions in the `Pre-request Scripts`.

As Postman comes with Lodash, you can use the [_.get()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get) function in the sandbox to get the data from the `stores` array. You would need to use `JSON.parse()` to correctly assign the data from the request body in the `_.get()` function.

```
let requestBody = _.get(JSON.parse(pm.request.body.raw), 'stores[0]')

pm.test("Check Body", () => {
    pm.expect(requestBody).to.have.keys(['city', 'name'])
})
```

Or something like this without Lodash:

```
let requestBody = JSON.parse(pm.request.body.raw)

pm.test("Check Body", () => {
    pm.expect(requestBody.stores[0]).to.have.keys(['city', 'name'])
})
```

More info on the `pm.*` API can be found here:

https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman-sandbox-api-reference/

Comment: Thank you @DannyDainton I can now able to validate the results successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pm.test` as you can see request body, content-type, response content in Run Results. Export Results has too many details.

Test Request Body:

```
pm.test(JSON.parse(pm.request.body));
```

Test URLEncoded with Request Body:

```
pm.test(JSON.stringify(pm.request.body.urlencoded.toObject(true)));
```

Test Raw Text in Request Body:

```
 pm.test(JSON.parse(pm.request.body.raw));
```

Example:

```
var reqBody = request.data; //JSON.parse(request.data);
tests["Data"] = reqBody.stores[0].city !== null;
```